# Angular 3 dropDown to select birth day

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, uidatepicker

I want to display 3 dropDowns : day,month, and year.

in order to select a birthDay.

Angular.ui datePicker has no this option.Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [`angular-date-dropdowns` library](https://github.com/rorymadden/angular-date-dropdowns) or [`Combodate` library](http://vitalets.github.io/combodate/)

I would prefer you use angular-date-dropdowns.. Here is an example:

```
<input rsmdatedropdowns ng-model="dob" />
```

Comment: Combodate looks greate but I prefer to use Angular, and I have alreadt try     'rsmdatedropdowns' but it doesnt work perfect.

Comment: I try again the 'rsmdatedropdowns'. when i choose day and then month , they are both disapeared

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? The library comes with an example.. are you able to run it?

Comment: No errors on console, I dont see any demo in GitHub

Comment: Finally I used 'rsmdatedropdown'. there was a bug there so it didnt work. I fixed it and it works nicely. 10x

Comment: @BrMe, what was the bug?

Comment: @Justin  look at this fiddle, there are some changes I did. I dont remember what exactly. but it works : http://jsfiddle.net/avime3156/anr8fv6k/